# converting multiple CSVs files to parquet in Rstudio

Tags: r, list, csv, parquet, converters

I have about 500 large CSV files in a folder. I would like to convert each of these files to parquet format so I can upload these to google cloud and analyze them on R server. I am trying the below solution but I am getting weird results.

```r
map_df_fread <- function(path, pattern = "*.csv") {
list.files(path, pattern, full.names = TRUE) %>%
map_df(~freadx)
}

mt <- map_df_fread(path="~/Desktop/Daily taxi"
,pattern="*.csv")
```

After this code, I get a weird result. In the environment tab on top right corner in R, for data mt, I am getting 0 obs. of 0 variables. Basically, R thinks I have no files in the directory. So I am unable to batch convert these 500 files. When I do one-one its possible, but I will need to do it 500 times. Please help I am at very early stage of R.

```r
write_parquet(mt, "poi.parquet")
```

Comment: Try to change your pattern to `.csv$` instead of `*.csv`.

Comment: That doesnt seem to work either..

Comment: Does `list.files` with your given parameters return anything?